# Chrome: Select field font-size and font-family ignoring stylesheets

Tags: css, forms, macos, google-chrome

In Chrome, the font size and font family of form 'select' fields is not following css rules as expected.

My stylesheets declare the font-family should be 'Open Sans', and font-size should be 14px.
But, it is reverting back to 'Lucida Grande' and 11px.

This screenshot of Chrome's developer tools sums it up - the Country select field is the item in question:

[image: form select font issue]

---

The following didn't fix the issue:

```
html, body, input, select, textarea, button {
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 13px;
}
```

---

Interestingly enough, it is only doing this on my machine (mac mini mavericks); testing on others (windows 7/8) in the same browser results in no error. Has anyone else dealt with this issue? Is there some setting necessary to override default values?

Answer (score 0):

One near-solutionis to use the following to increase the font size to 13px on Mac - but this results in a massive 48px on Windows:

```
select {
  font-size: -webkit-xxx-large;
}
```

Alternatively, the following would reset everything about the menulist appearance, to build up from scratch (font size/family take CSS rules or inherit):

```
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Ideally a simple font adjustment wouldn't require resetting everything about the menulist...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something unexpected happens with the cascading aspect of CSS, and it's clearly not an error introduced by the developer, then there's a good chance it has something to do with the `!important` command.  Someone may have applied `!import` to a style in some earlier part of the CSS.  Try applying it to your styles to see if it has an effect.

Comment: The !important directive is not the issue here. I'm able to reproduce the same problem with not a single !important directive anywhere in my stylesheets. In fact, I can reproduce the issue in the Chrome DOM inspector even when applying a font family style directly to the element. No matter what font family one instructs the SELECT element to utilize, it always uses "Lucida Grande" no matter what. This definitely looks like a bug.